# Where in this example does the google vr apply binocular distortion?

Tags: android, rendering, virtual-reality, google-vr

I am developing an app for google cardboard that will stream two videos, one to each eye, as to simulate 3D vision. I only intend to use the google vr sdk to simulate the binocular distortion that will be applied to each frame, however it's unclear from [this example](https://developers.google.com/vr/android/samples/treasure-hunt) which function actually applies the distortion.

```
/**
 * Draws a frame for an eye.
 *
 * @param eye The eye to render. Includes all required transformations.
 */
@Override
public void onDrawEye(Eye eye) {
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    ...
    // Apply the eye transformation to the camera.
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mView, 0, eye.getEyeView(), 0, mCamera, 0);

    // Set the position of the light
    Matrix.multiplyMV(mLightPosInEyeSpace, 0, mView, 0, LIGHT_POS_IN_WORLD_SPACE, 0);

    // Build the ModelView and ModelViewProjection matrices
    // for calculating cube position and light.
    float[] perspective = eye.getPerspective(Z_NEAR, Z_FAR);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mModelView, 0, mView, 0, mModelCube, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mModelViewProjection, 0, perspective, 0, mModelView, 0);
    drawCube();

    // Draw the rest of the scene.
    ...
}
```

This code snippet is described like so:

> This is the sequence of events:
>
> - The treasure comes into eye space.
> - We apply the projection matrix. This provides the scene rendered for the specified eye.
> - The Google VR SDK applies distortion automatically, to render the final scene.

However, this third step is not actually explained. Since I am not rendering and images, just using video from real life, I only need to use the part of the code that applies the the distortion, however it's unclear to me how exactly this happens.

If anybody has any ideas, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

public Distortion getApproximateInverseDistortion (float maxRadius, int numCoefficients)

Builds an inverse-distortion object with least-squares-fitted coefficients.

This is intended for implementing application-side custom distortion. Use .getCoefficients() on the returned object to retrieve the inverse distortion function's coefficients.

This is an approximate inverse, and using .distort() on the returned object will be faster but less accurate than using the distortInverse() method on the original. For useful results, the input distortion must be well-behaved in the 0..maxRadius range.

Example for 50 degree half-angle FOV (100 degrees total), this will create an inverse distortion where inverse.distort(r) approximately equals distortion.distortInverse(r) in the range r = 0 ... maxFovHalfAngle.

More info: https://developers.google.com/vr/android/reference/com/google/vr/sdk/base/Distortion

https://www.baekdal.com/insights/why-pretty-much-all-360-vr-videos-get-it-wrong